# How do you align divs to the right of a page

Tags: html, css

I am creating an admin dashboard with my website, right now including a sidebar on the left. I am wondering how I can align my divs to the right so the main dashboard could be there?

I've tried doing 'align' in CSS and as an attr. in HTML but I keep getting it attached to my sidebar

```
div {
  align: right;
}
```

I expected it to show on the right of the sidebar but what happened was that the main page connected to the sidebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
div {
  float: right;
}
```

It will place your div to the right off the page

Answer (score 0):

first, add this style for your sidebar:

```
.yourSideBar {
    float:left;
    }
```

then follow next for your div:

```
div {
   float:right;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-box:

in an html as :

```
<main>
<section class="dashboard"></section>
<aside class="right-sidebar"></aside>
</main>
```

you can style like this:

```
main{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
}

section{
  width:80%;
  background:#000;
}

.right-sidebar{
background:#ccc; 
width:20%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLEeYB

more here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/